# Unable to create web app in azure through Azure Management Library

Tags: azure, azure-management-api, dreamspark

I have trying to create a web app through [fluent Azure Management Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent).

I am currently on [DreamSpark](https://imagine.microsoft.com/en-us/catalog) Subscription.

Here is my program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set some variables...
            string rgName = "numbers1102rg";
            string appName = SdkContext.RandomResourceName("WebApp", 20);

            // Authenticate
            var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
                .FromFile(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION"));

            var azure = Azure
                .Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Authenticate(credentials)
                .WithDefaultSubscription();

            // Create the web app
            Console.WriteLine("Creating Web App...");
            var app = azure.WebApps.Define(appName)
                .WithRegion(Region.USEast)
                .WithNewResourceGroup(rgName)
                .WithNewFreeAppServicePlan()
                .DefineSourceControl()
                .WithPublicGitRepository("https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-dotnet-get-started")
                .WithBranch("master")
                .Attach()
                .Create();
            Console.WriteLine("Your web app is live at: https://{0}", app.HostNames.First());

            // Wait for the user
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I have also, done the azureauth.properties setup.

Here is the error it throws while creating:
[image]

I have also performed steps to be a contributor from here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/dotnet-sdk-azure-get-started?view=azure-dotnet

And the app is a contributor to that resource:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because the user for which access token is fetched doesn't have permission to create a resource (WebApp in your case) in the resource group you're using.

To fix this error, please assign a role (say a `Contributor`) to that user in the resource group you're using.

Please see this link regarding how you can assign role to a user using Azure Portal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure.

Comment: The app i am talking through is already a contributor. [Here](http://imgur.com/a/FhcU1)